# Jquery get total checkbox in current page and calculate no. of them are checked in page load

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get total number of checkbox in my current page and how many of them are checked using following scripts:

```
$(window).load(function() {
 var chk_total=$('input[type='checkbox'].order_row:checked').length;
    var in_total=$('input[type='checkbox'].order_row').length;
    if (chk_total == in_total) {
       alert("all cheked");
    }

 }
```

Html scripts:

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="order_row"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="order_row"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="order_row"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="order_row"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="order_row"/>
```

But above scripts doesn't working for me. Could please tell me why it's not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your js scripts has errors please update that as follow then try again.

```
var chk_total=$('input[type="checkbox"].order_row:checked').length;
var in_total=$('input[type="checkbox"].order_row').length;
if (chk_total == in_total) {
   alert("all cheked");
}
```

Or use following scripts:

```
   var chk_total=$('.order_row:checked').length;
    var in_total=$('.order_row').length;
    if (chk_total == in_total) {
       alert("all cheked");
    }
```